# Make domain folder act as root

Tags: html, .htaccess, server, subdomain, hosting

I have a domain for example `https://test.com` this domain contain a **full project** in `https://test.com/system`.

> Problem:

Whenever I write `<link ref="stylesheets" href="/style/main.css">` it search in the  domain root not in the **system** directory which the project in.

> What I have tried to do:

I have tried to edit all my path to be equal to `href="style/main.css"` instead of `href="/style/main.css"`.

This solution works but I won't do this every time I go in production mode.

> What I am trying to do:

I know there is a solution using `.htaccess` but I don't know how to write it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> `<link ref="stylesheets" href="./system/style/main.css">`

*or*

> `<link ref="stylesheets" href="../system/style/main.css">`.

If it still won't work, use three dots.

> `<link ref="stylesheets" href=".../system/style/main.css">`.

It has worked for me.

---

### ***To set a subdirectory as root with `.htaccess`***

It will depend, with some hosting services you only need to add this line:

> `RewriteBase   /system`

If that doesn't works for you, try this:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> # Map http://www.example.com to /system.
> RewriteRule ^$ /system/ [L]
> # Map http://www.example.com/x to /system/x unless there is a x in the web root.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /system/$1
> # Add trailing slash to directories within system
> # This does not expose the internal URL.
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^system/(.*[^/])$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]
> ```

Comment: I have used `href="system/style/main.css"` and it works for me but there is a way in .htaccess to set this subdiretory as root.. because I don't want to change all my css, js, images and others paths

Comment: Check the changes made.